# is it possible to clear same ranges of multiple sheets of the same spreadsheet in an easier way?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find a easier way to write the following

```
function Clearing() {
let monday = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XX").getSheetByName("Monday");
monday.getRange('B2:B').clearContent();
monday.getRange('E2:E').clearContent();
monday.getRange('H2:H').clearContent();
let tuesday = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XX").getSheetByName("Tuesday");
tuesday.getRange('B2:B').clearContent();
tuesday.getRange('E2:E').clearContent();
tuesday.getRange('H2:H').clearContent();
```

}

I also tried with getRangeList('B2:B','E2:E') without success

Comment: Since the ranges are not contiguous I don't see another way.  Is the problem it takes a long time to run?  Is it also that you do it for every day of the week, so the script gets long?  Also can you use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead of `openById()`?  Not really sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have noticed in the title its from the same Spreadsheet.  I changed the name from "Clearing" to "clearing" as its typical convention except for opjects.

```
function clearing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var days = ["monday","tuesday","wednesday","thursday","friday","saturday","sunday"];
  var i = 0;
  var sh = null;
  for( i=0; i<days.length; i++ ) {
    sh = ss.getSheetByName(days[i]);
    sh.getRange('B2:B').clearContent();
    sh.getRange('E2:E').clearContent();
    sh.getRange('H2:H').clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: after checking my ss again, I actually have an additional sheet for statistics which needs not to be cleared so your solution actually works best
thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Version 4 of Sheet API

```
function clearranges() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let clrrg = Sheets.newBatchClearValuesRequest();
  clrrg.ranges = ['Sheet0!B2:B','Sheet0!E2:E','Sheet0!H2:H'];//using stantdar A1 Notation
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchClear(clrrg,ss.getId());
}
```

Sheet API Version 4 must be enabled

[Values.batchClear](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchClear)

I found it worth reading throught [Guides](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts) at first and then take a look at [samples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `.getRangeList()`, you'll need to pass an [array of A1 Notations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations), (i.e. with brackets) rather than a list of arguments.

Something like this:

```
function clearing() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
  sheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName){
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRangeList(['B2:B','E2:E','H2:H']).clearContent()
  })
}
```

If you're trying to clear the same set of ranges on  *all* sheets in the spreadsheet, you can use `ss.getSheets()`:

```
function clearing() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
    .forEach(function(sheet){
      sheet.getRangeList(['B2:B','E2:E','H2:H']).clearContent()
    })
}
```

Comment: great,this is exactly what i was looking for
the original function worked properly but I try to reduce the length of the code as much as possible
thanks for your help and reactivity